# App Engine - Java Cache Control wont work

Tags: xml, file, google-app-engine, caching, static

This is a noobie question

I would like to add expires headers for static files.

I tried :

```
<static-files>
     <include path="/**.png" expiration="4d 5h" />
</static-files>
```

and put this in the *appengine-web.xml*

But everytime i deploy this on the egine, the engine wont work anymore.
Maybe i used the wrong location for the code?

Here is the full code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <!-- REQUIRED: CHANGE THE <application> TAG! -->
    <application>myname</application>
    <version>1</version>

        <static-files>        <include path="/**.png" expiration="4d 5h" />    </static-files>

    <system-properties>
        <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
    <property name="com.google.gdata.DisableCookieHandler" value="true"/> 



    <!-- OPTIONAL: Put in your configuration values in this section. -->
    <property name="com.google.ytd.BrandingTag" value=""/>
    <property name="com.google.ytd.LinkBackText" value=""/>
    <property name="appengine.orm.disable.duplicate.pmf.exception" value="false"/>
    <property name="com.google.ytd.RecaptchaPrivateKey" value=""/>
    <property name="com.google.ytd.RecaptchaPublicKey" value=""/>  
    </system-properties>


  <ssl-enabled>true</ssl-enabled>
  <sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>
  <threadsafe>false</threadsafe>


    <inbound-services>
    <service>mail</service>
  </inbound-services>
</appengine-web-app>
```

Comment: Please be specific about what way it doesn't work.

Comment: faced similar problem, I doubt that after overriding <include> with only png files, you woulnd't be able to access any other static files in the browser. Try adding all static resources in the include tag like js, css, etc